# Chrome extension scrape text from one page and display inline onload

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm having a bit of difficulty getting started on this as I'm quite horrid with javascript.   My goal is to scrape some text off of a page (that has nothing but the text I want on it) and load it inside of a floating div or something when I load another page.

In essence:

timer.html contains a timer that displays the current time and self-reloads every 10 seconds.
page.html is loaded, I want to display timer.html at the bottom of page.html

Note:  I don't own any of the source involved outside of my test envir, otherwise there's a million easier ways to do this.

Can help me with resources or code examples?